# moodle new user webservice invalid parameter

Tags: moodle

This is a bit frustrating,

I am trying to add new user using a web service , these are my parameters:

```
$user1 = new stdClass();
$user1->username = "testing";//trim(urlencode(filter_var($_POST['arr']['user_email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
$user1->password = "asdL1232";//trim(filter_var($_POST['arr']['user_password'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$user1->firstname = "testname";//isset($name[0]) ? urlencode($name[0]) : '';
$user1->lastname = "testlastname";//isset($name[1]) ? urlencode($name[1]) : '';
$user1->email = "tests@gmail.com";//urlencode(filter_var($_POST['arr']['user_email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$user1->auth = 'manual';
$user1->surname = 'asdsad';
$user1->country = 'Israel';
$user1->lang = 'he';
$user1->idnumber = '';
$user1->theme = 'standard';
```

and this is the server response:

"Invalid parameter value detected | ERRORCODE: invalidparameter"

I cannot understand which parameter is wrong...

can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this article: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Errors_handling_in_web_services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing this user object code i have seen following issue -

1. Invalid parameter value detected (surname is not exist in Moodle)
2. Passwords must have at least 1 non-alphanumeric characters.
3. Data too long for column 'country' (use IL country code)

for testing always enable debug mode on in moodle.

Comment: i have overcome this issue thanks , now i have another one for a diffrent function "Function ("core_user_update_users") is not a valid method for this service" , i have added this function to the same group as core_user_create_users